# configurar pdo_informix.dll en ubuntu server 20

Tags: php, ubuntu, informix

Estoy tratando de hacer funcionar este código en Ubuntu. Ya instalé xamp en ubuntu que viene a ser lamp todo bien; ahora bien, en php windows simplemente copie la librería *php_pdo_informix.dll* a la carpeta correspondiente y añadí como referencia la extensión en *php.ini* y pude conectarme a una base de datos informix sin problemas con este código.

```
class con_informix
{
    static public conectar_sai
    {
    
    $con_sai = new PDO("informix:host=".SAI_HOST."; service=9088; database=".SAI_BD."; server=".SAI_SERVER."; protocol=onsoctcp; EnableScrollableCursors=1", SAI_USER, SAI_PASS);
    return $con_sai;
    }   


    public function cargar_consulta($sql)
    {
        $respuesta = $con_sai()->prepare($sql);
        $respuesta->execute();
        return $respuesta;
    }
}
```

Todo me salió bien, ahora en ubuntu server 20 no encuentro la manera de hacer que funcione este código ya que tengo que configurar o copiar dicha librería dll, pero no sé dónde.

Comment: consulta, has tratado de buscar esa libreria para ubuntu?, supongo que debe existir algun equivalente

Comment: la busque por todos lados pero lo que entendi es que las librerias son con extension .so, y existe un pdo_informix.so segun lei pero no logro hacer que funcione siempre me pide Informix Client SDK, y bueno el hecho de ser principiante creo uq ehace que me complique nado muy perdido, espero que alguien me encuentre.

Comment: Nope, DLL es compilado pa windows. Debes buscar un `.so` de esa misma librería.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta todo lo que necesites para AÑÁDIR detalles

Comment: Revisaste que cumplas con los [requerimientos](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/informix-client-software-development-kit-client-sdk-and-informix-connect-system-requirements?mhsrc=ibmsearch_a&mhq=download%20informix%20csdk#linux)? Glibc y gcc son necesarios

Comment: Transformaste tu pregunta en una nueva, invalidando las respuestas que te dieron. Si es una pregunta de seguimiento, hace una nueva pregunta... tu pregunta, fue respondida correctamente

Comment: O sea, botó a la basura las respuestas??? Reversar! Si no marcas nada como aceptado y ni siquiera pones la solución que hayas encontrado tú mismo, créeme que la comunidad tendra CERO ganas de atender tus preguntas. Lo que está puesto ahora ni siquiera es una pregunta válida

Comment: Lo siento.. no fue la intension hasta ahora no encuentro la solucion solo edite la pregunta como me lo sugirieiron en ningun momento bote nada a la asura, perdon si parecio asi..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te han indicado, un DLL es una librería compilada y definida para ser usada por sistemas Windows. Por lo tanto, la idea es usar una compilación hecha para ser usada sobre *nix. Suele tener extensión `.so` (y por eso en el php.ini verás un poco de php_xyz.so).

Según la [documentación actual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php) de ese módulo, lo que indica es:

> para construir la extensión PDO_INFORMIX, el cliente *Informix Client SDK 2.81 UC1 o superior* debe estar instalado en el mismo sistema que PHP. El cliente *Informix Client SDK* está disponible en el [sitio de soporte oficial](http://www-306.ibm.com/software/data/informix/tools/csdk/) de IBM Informix.
>
> PDO_INFORMIX es una [*extensión PECL*](https://pecl.php.net/), por lo que se deben seguir las instrucciones en [Instalación de extensiones PECL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) para instalar la extensión PDO_INFORMIX. Use el comando `configure` para apuntar a la ubicación de sus librerías y headers en el Informix Client SDK, que sería algo como:
>
> bash$ ./configure --with-pdo-informix=/path/to/SDK[,shared]
>
> El comando `configure` por defecto usa el valor de la variable de entorno INFORMIXDIR.

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo por los datos efectivamente hice tal como indica la documentacion pero tengo un error justamente al agregar comando ./configure pero tengo errores /bin/bash build/config.sub........... si me podrias dar soporte.. ausber.arroba.punto.com estoy leyendo adiconalmente la documentacion para entenderlo mejor

Comment: Soporte no doy, por ese cobro ;) Ayuda, toda la que necesites, igual que todos acá; edita tu pregunta y **añade** lo que has probado para ver si debo editar algo en la respuesta. Añade los mensajes de error completos, **como texto**.

Comment: eso hare enseguida y si es necesario te pago el soporte Amigo

Answer (score 1):

**No es posible.**

*DLL:*

> Una biblioteca de enlace dinámico (DLL, por la sigla en inglés de
> dynamic-link library) es el término con el que se refiere a los
> archivos con código ejecutable que se cargan bajo demanda de un
> programa por parte del sistema operativo. Esta denominación es
> exclusiva a los sistemas operativos Windows siendo ".dll" la extensión
> con la que se identifican estos ficheros, aunque el concepto existe en
> prácticamente todos los sistemas operativos modernos.

En pocas palabras este tipo de archivo esta hecho para ser usado en `Windows`; requeririas una aplicacion de tercero para poder hacer el loeader de un archivo `dll` en linux y no es aconcejables... mira ya existe wine que levanta aplicaciones windows en linux y siempre hay uno que otro problema de compatibilidad o seguridad...

esto seria un apaño y no seria profesional; el camino correcto a seguir como te lo dijeron en los comentarios, es:

1. estudiar los requerimientos nativos para linux.
2. adecuar tu entorno de desarrollo (Instalar y configurar todo lo que necesites)
3. iniciar las pruebas de rendimiento y desarrollo.

Si no puedes hacer esto, lo mas conveniente seria pedir apoyo en DevOPS.